Automatic Kernel 6.8.0-45 upgrade crashes Virtualbox 6.1 on Ubuntu 22.04
The automatic Kernel 6.8.0-45 upgrade sent down yesterday (2024-08-13) crashes Virtualbox 6.1 on Ubuntu 22.04. I had to roll it back to Kernel 6.5.0-45 to get everything working.

Please file a bug report. AskUbuntu is not the bug tracker.

Also encountering this. Installing Virtualbox 7 from the official deb solves the error, but introduces a black screen.

I'm seeing the same thing with multiple VirtualBox installs. We're having to roll back the Kernel update and disable automatic updates.

If the next kernel fixes the issue you will not know.

That's a bold assumption. If only there was some way I could proactively test to see if it's fixed. At least for now, work can continue to get done.

The problem is "a Ubuntu kernel update which breaks VirtualBox 6.1.x" per this thread https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=112043.
Solution (which worked for me) is remove VB 6.1 and install 7.0. I followed the instructions here:   How to upgrade VirtualBox 6.1.38 to 7.0 on Ubuntu 22.04? which is based on this site: https://kifarunix.com/upgrade-virtualbox-6-x-to-virtualbox-7-x-on-ubuntu-debian/?expand_article=1
I did have some problems understanding the command line 'spacing': some two-line commands are supposed to be done together.  For me the source (second) was less confusing.
On initial boot of VB I did receive an error re: USB.  I followed some notes I had made earlier:   Add every user who needs to access USB devices from a VirtualBox guests to the group
vboxusers. Either use the OS user management tools or run the following command as root: sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers username.
Follow that with a reboot end enjoy running the VMs again!
